# override default css style

Tags: html, css

In "my" template I override the style of radio buttons and labels like this:

```
[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
[type="radio"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: .28s ease;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

[type="radio"] + label:before,
[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: .28s ease;
}

/* Unchecked styles */
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #5a5a5a;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #5a5a5a;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
}

/* Checked styles */
[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #8bc34a;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
          transform: scale(1.02);
}

/* Radio With gap */
[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + label:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #8bc34a;
}

[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + label:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #8bc34a;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
          transform: scale(0.5);
}

/* Disabled Radio With gap */
[type="radio"].with-gap:disabled:checked + label:before {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

[type="radio"].with-gap:disabled:checked + label:after {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

/* Disabled style */
[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-color: #BDBDBD;
}
```

Now I want to apply a complete other style to radio buttons and labels in a div and I've tried this:

```
.cc-selector-2 input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none !important; /* hide the radio button */
}

.cc-selector-2 input:active +.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc { opacity: .9; }
.cc-selector-2 input:checked +.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc { 
    -webkit-filter: none;
       -moz-filter: none;
            filter: none;
}

<div class="cc-selector-2">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Age, "Age", new { id = "age1", @value = "shakegender", @name = "radio" })
                <label class="drinkcard-cc m" id="age1" for="age1"></label>
            </div>
```

I can't figur it out why it's not overriding and tried many things like linking to the id (#age1) of my radio button but nothing works.

Thank you.

Comment: [This might answer your question](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Are you using same stylesheet or another one?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the two different styles within 2 different CSS files? If so, ensure that the additional styling style sheet is below the first in your `<head>` tag.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/NewDefaultRadio.css"  /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/AddiotionalRadioStyles.css"  /> 

</head>
```

Comment: yes, I have two different css files but it seems right, the default overrides for the radio buttons is loading first, below that I'm referencing the additional css file. So in generally my additional css code should work and it should override my default style?